# woocommerce product "custom info input" field option

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a WP site at the moment with woocommerce and want to be able to allow to customer to add information on the product order page that will come through with the order.
The site offers slate engraved house signs, so I'd like the customer to be able to choose the product from the shop ie., a sign at say 300mmx200mm, then have the option to input:
1 what text they would like
2 what font (choice of 5)
3 what colour (choice of 5)

Once this is all in, they can proceed to checkout and the details come in with the order.
Hope this makes sense :-)
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [WC Fields Factory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/) It's a plugin to add custom fields to your products, which will be carried over to cart, checkout, order and email too.

Comment: Fantastic! thanks for your help. works like a treat :-)

Answer (score 0):

WooThemes has a [Product Addons Plugin](https://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) that should be able to help you add textfield attributes to products. I didn't use it myself, but as you see in the description, there is an example that uses "Custom Engraving". Also check out the video they provide for additional info.

Have a great day btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple scenario. Choose variable product and add variations for your product so that people can choose one of your variation and definitely those variations will come along with the order as well.